# How do I Fulton child soldiers?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, Mission 23 Kaz wants me to Fulton child soldiers to save me a lot of time. How do I do that?

Comment: @Nolonar All Kaz says is "there should be some way to Fulton kids."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Side Ops 113 unlocks the child Fulton.

To unlock the Side Ops, you will have to complete Mission 26.

Answer (score 18):

You don't actually need to research the Child-Safe Fulton Device to Fulton the kids.

What you can do is call for a jeep - Soviet or American, doesn't matter - stack three kids in it, and then call for another Diamond Dogs vehicle.

Diamond Dogs vehicles are, just like D-Horse and D-Walker, rigged to Fulton themselves when their presence in the combat zone is no longer required. This costs you NOTHING. They auto-Fulton themselves when you call for a new vehicle.

This is actually the most economical way to get people out, ironically. Every vehicle has a dirt-cheap 1,000 GMP deployment cost (fair warning: this may be related to the cost of your helicopter calls, I use the cheapest helicopter because I'm a tightwad.) Thing is, 1,000 GMP is only 100 GMP more expensive than the cost of Fultoning three guys by themselves! And it cuts your Fulton usage down to precisely zero, meaning you won't have to call for more Fulton devices mid-mission, which can save you an absolute truckload in the long run!

Comment: Woo! Party Bus!

Answer (score 4):

You can place them in vehicles and fulton those.

Comment: This assumes that he's able to Fulton  vehicles though. Which you need to upgrade to be able to do.

Comment: I can Fulton vehicles. I have the Cargo +2 upgrade and all. I saw that but didn't think of it at the time.

Comment: this is how I got around it - jeeps are good for that. expensive to drop in a jeep (or steal one) for every 3 child soldiers, then fulton it out however.