# How to get Fulton for children?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I need to get Fulton for children, but after the Side Ops # 133 I'm not getting a prescription. So how to get it?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235385/how-do-i-fulton-child-soldiers suggests it's Side Op #113 that you need?

Comment: I completed 113 missions. I do not want to start over the game if it is a bug :(